# Python: Unable to match a period (in a non-capturing group) that is followed by a word break

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex like this one: `r"credit\s+card\s+(?:numbers?|no[s\.]?)\b"`. I would like to match a phrase like "credit card no." (including the period). However, it currently will only match the part of the phrase *preceding* the period.

```
>>> re.search(r"credit\s+card\s+(?:numbers?|no[s\.]?)\b", "credit card no.")
# <re.Match object; span=(0, 14), match='credit card no'>
```

This seems to have to do with the word break sign `\b` (and the fact that there is a word break between `no` and `.`: if I remove `\b`, the full phrase can be matched:

```
>>> re.search(r"credit\s+card\s+(?:numbers?|no[s\.]?)", "credit card no.")
# <re.Match object; span=(0, 15), match='credit card no.'>
```

I wonder if there is a way to modify the regex to make it capture the period (when it is actually present in text).

EDIT:
Updated the regex to accommodate both singular and plural forms of "number"

Possible input strings could be:

- credit card number
- credit card numbers
- credit card no
- credit card no.
- credit card nos

I include the word boundary for potential false positive matches for "credit card no" as it could match strings like "credit card notification" without the word break

Comment: Can you give examples of the succesive text? for example, why you need `\b` from the first place

Comment: Why don't you simply remove the `\b` then? Please provide more input strings to match.

Comment: space or `.` are word boundaries as theirselves

Comment: According to your edit, I would simply replace `\b` with `$` or `\s` - [demo](https://regex101.com/r/2uRP12/1/)

Comment: don't replace with the `\s`, I just tested that and it fails to match the 'credit card nos'. The replace with the `$` works though on the first version of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `\b` where it is expected to assert the end of words, after word chars only:

```
r'credit\s+card\s+(?:numbers?\b|no(?:s\b|\b\.)?)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5n9nom/1).

`(?:numbers?|no[s\.]?)\b` is turned into `(?:numbers?\b|no(?:s\b|\b\.)?)` and matches:

- `numbers?\b` - `number` or `numbers` as whole words, no word char is allowed immediately to the right of these strings
- `|` - or
- `no` - `no` substring followed with...
- `(?:s\b|\b\.)?` - an optional 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - `s\b` - `s` not followed with a word char
  - `|` - or
  - `\b\.` - word boundary and a dot.

**NOTE**: If you do not want any word char to appear after the `.`, add `\B` non-word boundary, `\b\.` => `\b\.\B`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I ended up figuring it out on my own, in a slightly different form than yours. But your version is more elegant than mine. Thanks!